# Python web scraping nested dict key pairs - AttributeError

Tags: python, list, dictionary, web-scraping, nested

I'm attempting to scrape PGA stats from the API below.

```
url = 'https://statdata.pgatour.com/r/stats/current/02671.json?userTrackingId=exp=1594257225~acl=*~hmac=464d3dfcda2b2ccb384b77ac7241436f25b7284fb2eb0383184f48cbdff33cc4'
response = requests.get(url)
pga_stats = response.json()
```

I would like to only select the nested keys identified in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6sZt.png). I've been able to traverse to the 'year' key with the below code, but I receive the following AttributeError for anything beyond that.

```
 test = pga_stats.get('tours')[0].get('years')
        (prints reduced dictionary)

 test = pga_stats.get('tours')[0].get('years').get('stats')
       'list' object has no attribute 'get'
```

My end goal is to write this player data to a csv file.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`pga_stats.get('tours')[0].get('years')` returns a list, not a dict. You actually want to use the [`get`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_dictionary_get.asp) method on it's first element, like this:

```py
test = pga_stats.get('tours')[0].get('years')[0].get('stats')
```

Comment: Thank you! makes sense now. I can retrieve all players stats with 
     'test = pga_stats.get('tours')[0].get('years')[0].get('stats')[0].get('details')'.
Do you have any recommendations on how to convert to a dataframe as there are still nested key value pairs at this level? Much appreciated for the help

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(test,orient='Index')` enters the plrName and statValues as key value pairs but I would like to have those as row values if possible